# Bash script saving output of pipe sed to variable

Tags: bash

Why doesn't this work?

```
 newAns=$(${answer} | sed 's/\[//')
```

I'm trying to edit my $answer variable to take out the '[' and save it to a new variable.

Currently gives me an error saying "[foo]: command not found"

$answer = [foo]
echo $newAns = foo]

Comment: You probably meant `echo $answer`?

Comment: Hopefully not -- without quotes, as in `echo "$answer"`, it runs afoul of [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: This should also work : `newAns=$(echo "$answer" |sed 's/\[//')`  , then `echo "$newAns"` will give output: `foo]`  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$( ... )` runs a command.

`${answer} | sed` is a pipeline that runs the command `${answer}` and pipes its output into `sed`.

`sed` is a valid command, but your `$answer` is not (it's just a string).

The easiest solution is to not use a pipeline or external command at all:

```
newAns="${answer#\[}"
```

will remove a leading `[`.